# Why character pointer cannot be used to pass in gets() and scanf() functions?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

In one of the online code competition they give the one problem and the solution code of problem have to write in this funcion

```
char* iteration(char* input1) { // write code here}
```

While I am writing solution in my Code::Blocks IDE in windows, I've written main function as follows

```
int main(){
char *input1,*ans;

printf("Enter The Expression:");
//scanf("%s",input1);
//scanf("%s",&input1);
//gets(input1);

/*All the commented statements compiled without errors and warning but generated exe file stoped immediately after this statements */
printf("\nInput 1 is: %s",input1);
ans=iteration(input1);
printf("\nAns is: %s",ans);

getch();
return 0;}
```

So I want to take input in character pointer and want to pass in function.But I cant't because scanf and gets do not work with charcater pointer.

I know that  that by taking Input as character array and then copy it into the character string using strcpy() is work well. But I do not know the what is maximum length of input they try and I also Want to preffer that complete code with only uisng character pointer

Is it possible to use scanf and gets with character pointer ? why?

If yes where I am going wrong?

If not how should I pass argument and process character pointer.

**Why code compiled without errors and warning?**

Answer (score 4):

You *can* pass a character pointer to `fgets` (but you should perhaps then use [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)). However, a literal string is generally a *read-only* array (in the [code segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) of your [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable)) which cannot be overwritten.

Here is a silly way to pass a pointer to `fgets`:

```
#define MYSIZE 128
char *str = malloc(MYSIZE);
if (!str) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
memset (str, 0, MYSIZE);
if (fgets(str, MYSIZE-1, stdin)) {
  printf("got line: %s\n", str);
}
```

But you really should use `getline` instead. It will do the `malloc` for you. Of course *you* need to later `free(str)`

If you prefer to use [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) read *carefully* its documentation then use it. In particular, notice there how you can pass the maximal string (or word) length, and that you always should test the scanned item count result.

Comment: Then don't use them. But without any files, how would you have interesting side effects?

Comment: fgets() can be used to get input if the FILE * argument is stdin.

Answer (score 0):

Constants, by definition, cannot be modified. That's what makes them constant.

```
char *input1="NANpp";
```

This makes `input1` point to the constant "NANpp". Thus `input1` points to something that cannot be modified. But then `iteration` tries to modify the thing `input1` points to. That won't work.

Comment: If  I remove  "NANpp", than also it do not work. what are you say about this?

Comment: @AkshayPethani I'd have to see the code, but likely it would be because then `input1` would be dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: If you remove `="NaNpp"` the pointer is *uninitialized* and that is a huge *undefined behavior*

Comment: I'd appreciate it if the downvoter would explain the reason for the downvote.

Comment: It should be possible to configure your compiler to issue a warning if a pointer to a constant is stored in a pointer variable that isn't const-qualified.